# Python package not available in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, module

I am trying to run multiple python files at the same time. Apparently, the best way to do this is by using a bash file in Ubuntu. So I've started setting that up and thus also installing all the necessary packages. But I've arrived at the package simply named 'google' because I need `from google.cloud.sql.connector import connector` to be able to run. But when I type `sudo apt install google` it returns

`Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package google`

Note running `apt-cache search --names-only '^google.*'` results in the list of available packages that contain the 'google' in its title if I am not misunderstood. This returns a long list with a lot of packages, but none of them simply named google.

Does anyone know how I can access this module anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Type this command :

```bash
pip install cloud-sql-python-connector
```

But because ***the project is in Beta***, its recommanded to use a Virtual informations.
For mode detailed infos :

- [Cloud SQL Python](https://pypi.org/project/cloud-sql-python-connector/)
- [Python Virtual Environments and Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)